# PHP: Using DOM classes to build <script> elements

Tags: php, entity, domdocument

I have an HTML generator that uses the DOM classes to build documents and produce HTML. My target is HTML-compatible XHTML as outlined in Appendix C of the XHTML 1.0 spec.

This is a problem producing `<script>` elements:

```
$document = new \DOMDocument();
$element = $document->createElement('script');
$script = $document->createTextNode('console.log(1 && 1);');
$element->appendChild($script);
$document->appendChild($element);
echo $document->saveXML($document->childNodes[0]);
```

Actual output:

```
<script>console.log(1 &amp;&amp; 1);</script>
```

Desired output:

```
<script>console.log(1 && 1);</script>
```

How do I get the desired output with the entities not escaped?

The correct answer must account for the fact that this situation occurs in a generator that generates all sorts of HTML elements, not just `<script>`, and generates proper XHTML. (That's why I use `saveXML` instead of `saveHTML` in the first place.) If an answer causes the generator to fail or misproduce other HTML elements, it isn't the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't [`saveXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php), use [`saveHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php).

```
$document = new \DOMDocument();
$element = $document->createElement('script');
$script = $document->createTextNode('console.log(1 && 1);');
$element->appendChild($script);
$document->appendChild($element);
echo $document->saveHTML($document->childNodes[0]);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/63H0L

In XML an `&` is marking an entity.

Comment: Update: I had to unaccept this answer because I remembered why I used `saveXML` instead of `saveHTML` in the first place. My target is HTML-compatible XHTML as outlined in Appendix C of the XHTML 1.0 spec. I can't get proper XHTML with `saveHTML()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using change saveXML to saveHTML

```
echo $document->saveHTML($document->childNodes[0]);
```

Comment: This would generate invalid XML (although the OP probably doesn't want XML anyway).

Comment: It would also break the generation of other HTML elements that need escaped entities.